# How to create a gray UIImage from SF Symbol?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a model called `Contact` with an optional property called `imageData` of type `Data`, and a computed property called `image` of type `UIImage` that tries to initiate an `UIImage` from the `imageData` property, and if `imageData` is nil then it initiates an `UIImage` from SF Symbols.

I am using the computed property `image` to show the image in a `List` by calling `Image(uiImage: contact.image)`.

In my case, the `imageData` property is nil.

I want the color to be gray, but it is black, and I want to color the image inside the computed property.

https://github.com/fawzialrifai/Contacts2

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct Contact: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var imageData: Data?
    var image: UIImage {
        if let imageData = imageData {
            return UIImage(data: imageData)!
        } else {
            return UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")!.withTintColor(.gray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
}

struct ContactList: View {
    var contacts = [Contact(name: "Fawzi")]
    var body: some View {
        List(contacts) { contact in
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Image(uiImage: contact.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                Text(contact.name)
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 8)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I want to color the image inside the computed property* - why is such self-limitations?

Comment: @Asperi I want the code to be clean and I don't want to set the gray color if the user has an image, and I don't want to check if the user has an image or not in the view to apply the color, that's why I need to set the color for the placeholder image in the computed property.

Comment: Ok, but you mixed model layer with presentation layer (architecture error), creating artificial problem, which is now a blocker... hm... can't say it worth that. I would have just optional data image in model and everything else handle in view.

Answer (score 1):

```
return Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
     .renderingMode(.template)
     .foregroundColor(.gray)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change the tint color for the image you should use render mode `alwaysTemplate`

Try updating the following line.

```
return UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")!.withTintColor(.gray, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's another approach, if you want to use `Image.foregroundColor(.gray)`

```
var avatarImage : Image {
    if let imageData = imageData, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        return Image(uiImage: image)
    } else {
        return Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
               .foregroundColor(.gray) as! Image
    }
}
```